# How to get the layout soi that each row displays three items and are spaced apart evenly?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, layout, bootstrap-4

Been trying to find out a way to display three items in each row and are spaced evenly apart using react js and bootstrap.

I have been trying for hours today and had trouble finding out how to incorporate grid layouts on the page. I got it to render varying amounts of 3-4 items on each row without spacing which creates a messy look. But I do not want that. I want to render 3 items each row, with spacing between.

```
import React from "react";

const Recipes = (props) => (
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     { props.recipes.map((recipe)=> {
        return (
        <div key={recipe.recipe_id } style={{display:"flex", flexDirection:"column", justifyContent:"space-between"}}>
            <img src={recipe.image_url} alt={recipe.title} style={{width:"200px", height:"200px"}}/>
            <h3>{ recipe.title }</h3>
            <h5>{`By: ${ recipe.publisher}`}</h5>
         </div>
            )
        })}

    </div>
    </div>
)

export default Recipes;
```

I got it to render varying amounts of 3-4 items on each row without spacing which creates a messy look. But I do not want that. I want to render 3 items each row, with spacing between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap for the row class, but manually styling the rest with flexbox.  I haven't used Bootstrap in a little while but you should be able to wrap each of your elements (img, h3 & h5) in className col-md-4 to get 3 consistent columns. (md-4 because they have 12 columns in their grid and 12 / 4 =3 ).

Comment: Glad to hear it! Thanks for letting me know.